# Is makeup generally tzanua on women

Tags: halacha, women, tznius-modesty, even-haezer, beauty

According to Halacha, are there any issues of tzniut for a woman to wear certain types of makeup?

In general, I see it is accepted in the *Frum* world, but are there any types of makeup that could be problematic (especially for a married woman)?

Comment: Minhag Izevel ? וַיָּב֥וֹא יֵה֖וּא יִזְרְעֶ֑אלָה וְאִיזֶ֣בֶל שָׁמְעָ֗ה וַתָּ֨שֶׂם בַּפּ֚וּךְ עֵינֶ֙יהָ֙ וַתֵּ֣יטֶב אֶת־רֹאשָׁ֔הּ וַתַּשְׁקֵ֖ף בְּעַ֥ד הַחַלּֽוֹן this is just one source there are other sources showing that it's permitted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makeup has always be worn by Jewish women, as an example see the gemara in [Moed Katan 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.9b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> And a woman may engage in all of her usual cosmetic treatments on the
> intermediate days of a Festival. The Sages taught in a baraita: These
> are the cosmetic treatments of women that are permitted: She may paint
> her eyelids, she may remove unwanted hair [pokeset], and she may put
> rouge on her face.

As R Anthony Manning describes at length in his book on the topic ([Reclaiming Dignity](https://mosaicapress.com/product/reclaiming-dignity/)), *tzniut* is not just a question of rules but also of attitude, in relation to the local community. As such, **a woman which wears make-up in a way aligned with her community is perfectly *tzanua*. Were she to wear overly aggressive makeup to attract attention on herself, in a way that deviates from local norms and customs, that would not be.**

R Yitzchak Yaacov Fuchs writes it up in [Halichos Bas Yisrael](https://menuchapublishers.com/products/halichos-bas-yisrael-volumes-i-ii) (vol. 1, p. 204)

> Although it is proper for a woman to make herself up attractively when
> she is alone with her husband, she should not exaggerate when going
> out in public.